# Could not convert variant if type (Array Variant) into type (OleStr)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, fastreport

When try dynamicly bind TfrxBarCodeView from delphi get error Could not convert variant if type (Array Variant) into type (OleStr).

```
var
     barcode: TfrxComponent;
     value  : String;
begin  
  barcode := frxBarcode.FindObject('BarCode1');

  value  := '184577787878';

  if barcode is TfrxBarCodeView then
     TfrxBarCodeView(barcode).BarCode.Text := value;
```

in frxBarcode I have:

[image]

Comment: try declaring `value` as a string variable

Comment: @Fabrizio  my mistake, value is string variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should set the Text of the barcode view itself instead of the text of the barcode of the barcode view, so:

```
TfrxBarCodeView(barcode).Text := value;
```

instead of

```
TfrxBarCodeView(barcode).BarCode.Text := value;
```

Tried to add a reference, but online documentation seems to be non-existent. But I bumped into [this snippet](https://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?showtopic=9941) on the FastReports forum, and [this one](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/16267776/) in some, I don't know, website. Both are using `TfrxBarCodeView.Text` rather than `TfrxBarCodeView.Barcode.Text`.